# loss of x? loss in y?

Tags: prepositions

I am a non-native writer and am writing some English article.

Here I am confused about the use of preposition with loss. For instance,

> The system incurs the loss *of* energy and time
> The system incurs the loss *in* energy and time

Which one is more correct? Is there any difference in meaning?

Comment: They are both correct. “Loss of” is probably more idiomatic.

Comment: What, though, is wrong with “The system loses energy and time”? Is that not what you are trying to say?

Comment: There are shades of meaning: *in* suggests the way the loss takes place or how the loss occurs (you could also use *as* or *through*), *of* suggests a more abstract loss of some quantity or property. Compare *loss of money* and *loss in Bitcoin trading*.

Comment: _incurs the loss_ is very unclear. Is the system inefficient? Does it need to be redesigned? What does the loss come from? Is the energy loss proportional to time loss? Which is more troublesome?